# Re-Painting Concrete porch

Tags: concrete, paint, exterior, repainting

Hi I have a concrete porch with peeling and cracking paint. Do I need to sand it and then power-wash it before repainting. I tried using an orbital sander with 60 grit sandpaper but it just kept peeling and peeling. I was out there for an hour and no luck at all. I am desperate to find a solution and would rather not hire a painter? Some pictures are below:

[image: Cement Patch on cracks & peeling paint]

[image: Holes where termite treatment was done]

[image: Close up of peeling paint]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. If the current paint isn't adhering well, then after adding another layer you'll just watch both peel off.

Comment: Yes that is what I am afraid of. I am going to rent a belt sander with 36 GRIT sand paper and shred it off.

Comment: Why not get a wire brush attachment for your drill and do it the easy way?
You can use paint remover as well - the expensive kind $15 a gallon works fantastic.